# Hive insert overwrite not having value in HDFS part file for a managed table. I am running the hive query as a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hive, hiveql

Below mentioned is my shell script. I am already having a hive table from which below mentioned maximum date is taken into  a variable. It was working correctly and I used to get the maximum date into a variable, I am running this hive query as a shell script.

Now the Hive version was updated to Hive 3, I am getting the maximum date into a variable also insert overwrite is working fine in hive UI but not in shell script.

```
output_db="db_name"
hive -hivevar output_db=$output_db -hivevar parq_loc=$parquet_loc -e 'set hive.auto.convert.join=false;drop table if exists ${output_db}.table_summary;CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${output_db}.table_summary(mid varchar(30),`Date` date,Txn int,Collect decimal(18,2),Max_date date)ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe" STORED AS INPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat" OUTPUTFORMAT "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat" LOCATION "${parq_loc}/table_summary/";'
var= $(hive -hivevar source_db="$output_db" -e 'set hive.auto.convert.join=false;select max(`date`) from ${source_db}.table;')
hive -hivevar output_db=$output_db -hivevar max_date=$var -e 'set hive.auto.convert.join=false;insert overwrite table ${output_db}.table_summary select mid,`Date`,txn,collect,to_date("${max_date}") as `Max_date` from ${output_db}.table where `Date`>=add_months(trunc("${max_date}","MM"),-1);'
```

Comment: Please format your code/output/errors ( See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) and ask a clear question re what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

When taking query results to a variable will have header in Hive 3, while running in shell script.
You should give the below properties before writing the query.

```
"hive -hivevar --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e"
```